# Get the name of the current msi installation file from an Installer class

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer, deployment-project

It is possible to get the name of the current installation file (.msi) from the Installer class of custom action ?

I need something like this:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        **var fileName = CurrentMSIFileName();**
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: after 11years, have you found a solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution based on [Christopher Painter's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16814980/2696230) is by using `OriginalDatabase` property. Now I am able to get the msi installer file name in both during installation and uninstallation